# Vue.js - component inside component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I do have my component called Grid. Inside this component I load JSON data from server and i render them. They are mostly string and integers. Sometimes the JSON contains HTML like `<strong>myvalue</stong>` so I render the data with three brackets `{{{` and `}}}`.

The thing is when the HTML is not pure HTML but component like `<my-component my-param="1"></my-component>`. How to tell to Vue.js to render this coponent? All I get is the HTML purely printed into grid.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something like this: https://github.com/gurghet/vue-smart-table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to compile again that piece of code you've loaded from remote.**

*ps: I will use jQuery to manipulate the DOM.*

> Inside this component I load JSON data from server and i render them.

I'll assume you have a function named "loadAndRenderFromServer()", please adapt the code below to fits you.

Eg: If your grid has the markup `<div id='grid'>`

```
// vuecomponent.js
export default {
    [...]

    methods: {
        loadAndRenderFromServer() {
            // first, load remote content and insert into #grid

            // now, compile
            this.$compile($("#grid").get(0));
        }
    },

    [...]
}
```

You may need to use "decompile" if your component starts to duplicate the loaded content. Check into VueJS docs for **compile** and **decompile** methods.

Comment: "I will use jQuery to manipulate the DOM" seems like missing the point of Vue.

Comment: Pretty close man. I do have v-for on my JSON data. It's array with datasets. Each dataset represent table row. So I just do this.data = response.data and that's it. If I do call compile afterwards, will it work?

Comment: @ceejayoz, sorry but you're wrong. You can do simple manipulations to DOM with vue too, but there is nothing wrong in use jQuery or other libraries together within vue.

Comment: @grafa, compile will render the html code again through your component. You can call compile once for all rows as i mentioned, or you can run it for each row. BUT, running for each row will be massive and will have overload of processing. I recomend to call it once, if possible.

Don't forget to check the docs, i'm not an expert yet. xD

Comment: @RicardoVigatti Just because you can doesn't mean you should, in many cases. I see people doing stuff like `$(this.$els.whatever).text('foobar');` which wastes Vue's reactivity and templating system.

Comment: @ceejayoz, you're right about your example, but not about mine. There is already a lot of discussions about VueJS and jQuery on the internet, vue forums, etc. We're not going any further discussing about this here.

Comment: @grafa, you can use whatever you prefer, being pure VueJS, jQuery or any other library, your code won't be more or less "correct" because of this.

Comment: To the topic: great, works, I love you. To the jQuery: I switched to vanilla JS like a half a year ago. Since every browser support querySelector I don't need jQuery anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Using `v-html` (which is equivalent to `{{{}}}`) will not render what's inside it if it's a component.

Instead try to use `<slot>` in your parent template.

Otherwise, if you want dynamic components you need to use `<component>` and if you want content inside those dynamic component you need to use `<slot>`s.

I would suggest you to use something like

```
<component :is="myComponent" />
```

and inside the models of those components put some `<slot>`s to insert arbitrary content.

Comment: Thank you. So in my v-for where I do render table cell data with {{{ and }}} I should use <slot> instead? Wil that render the array item?

Comment: Please check the documentation for more details: https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots